# Force node modules to be reinstalled

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Nodejs site at http://fitbit-export.azurewebsites.net/. When I do a deploy from Github, Azure will only update `node_modules` if what already existed in `node_modules` does not match what's in `package.json`.

This means that if I have a version spec like `a@^1.0.0`, and `a@1.0.1` is published, Azure will not install `a@1.0.1` unless I update my `package.json` to request `a@^1.0.1`.

I'm guessing that Azure does this because it makes deploys faster, but it is a bit surprising for me, since I would expect deploying an app with `"a": "^1.0.0"` to receive `a@1.0.1` if it's available.

I can work around this by manually updating all entries in my `package.json`. However, is there a way to tell Azure to wipe my entire `node_modules` and do a fresh `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the default deployment script for Web Apps.

To get the default script use azure-cli to

```
azure site deploymentscript --node
```

`deploy.cmd` is the deployment script, in it you can see the package restoring command:

```
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
```

You could customize the command here or any other steps taken.

In order to use the customized script, check `deploy.cmd` along with the generated `.deployment` file into your source control, so that it will be deployed along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As @itaysk said, you can try to customize the deployment script for your webapp.

As references, there are some valuable and helpful documents I think.

1. Deployment for App Service, https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment
2. Customizing deployments for App Service, https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments
3. Deployment hooks for App Service，https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `npm install` which azure runs automatically doesn't update any existing modules if the version specified in package.json is lower than the module installed, or at least that's the case for the caret (^).

Instead of deleting the entire node_modules on the remote server each time (which will a long time) just update `.deployment` to run `npm update` after the packages are installed.

run `azure site deploymentscript --node` in your root repository that you are pushing to azure.

This generates:

`.deployment` and `deploy.cmd`

We only care about `.deployment.

Update `.deployment` script to add these lines:

```
:: 4. Update npm packages
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! update
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

To the deployment section:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 2. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  :: 3. Install npm packages
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"

  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: 4. Update npm packages
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! update
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  popd
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end
```

This installs your packages and then updates them to the correct version.

Check it's worked by opening a cmd and going to the directory with `deploy.cmd` and typing "deploy.cmd" to run it and examine the output.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you see that because Azure Web App [automates the deployment using npm install --production](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/) so it does not install devDependencies. Could you please rename devDependencies to dependencies in your package.json?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `devDependencies`.